# Pass more/multiple argument to Python subprocess.call

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I can run `ps aux | grep python_script.py` and get the details of the process running the script. I want to be able to run the same command from python script.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ps", "aux"])
```

works well, however tried these lines but both returns error,

```
call(["ps", "aux", "|", "grep", "python_script.py"])
call(["ps", "aux", "| grep python_script.py"])
```

Returns error, can someone please advise me on how to run `ps aux | grep python_script.py` from command line

Comment: Please read well b4 commenting, I asking of how to pass more arguments, that is a simple case which is NOT application to me. I have seen that solution but still did not solve my problem. Simple  call(["ps", "aux"])  works, but I have more argument to pass

Comment: Why are you using `grep` instead of just filtering the `ps` output in Python code? That would avoid the need for a shell pipeline at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too considerate about security you can set  `shell` argument to `True`. It will then instead of a `list`, take a `string` as the command. In that way it act's like a shell.

```
from subprocess import call
call("ps aux | grep python_script.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @user1767754 that works, please is there a way I can pass the returned to a value and possibly decide the correct PID from the list returned. I tried result = call("ps aux | grep python_script.py", shell=True). But print (result)  is 0

Comment: The linked duplicate already shows how to do this. Or you could read the documentation on the Python `subprocess` module. There are several well-documented ways to get the output of the subprocess, using `check_output`, `communicate`, or the `stdout` stream directly.

Comment: @Paullo What are you exactly trying to do, get the `PID` of the running process?